# Docrine2 findBy null .. what is happening here

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I use

```
$em->getRepository()->findBy(array('download' => null),null,10);
```

it is working fine as expected returning rows in null values for columns

However when I use

`$em->getRepository()->findBy(array('download' => array('',NULL)),null,10);`

it is ignoring the null values and is just working for blank values..

Can I body explain me what is happening out there ..

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `NULL` to `null`.

Comment: when you use this way it convert to `in` and it must work you can use `or` too http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#conditional-operators